# Не работает OnTriggerEnter в Unity C#

Tags: c#, unity3d

Только начал разбираться в Unity. Пытаюсь сделать так, чтобы при движении кубика, когда он соприкасается с другим кубиком или другой кубик оказывается внутри моего главного кубика, увеличивался счетчик counter на единицу. Однако почему-то ни OnCollision, ни OnTriggerEnter не работают. Когда мой кубик перемещается на место более маленького кубика, то ни одно из событий не срабатывает, хотя маленький кубик находится внутри моего главного. Что не так? Код:

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;

public class MainCube : MonoBehaviour
{

    private int counter = 0;
    private string text = "";

    private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {

        if (collision.gameObject.tag == "FoodCube")
        {
            collision.transform.position = new Vector3(Random.Range(0f, 28.5f), 0.25f, Random.Range(0f, 28.5f));
            counter++;
        }
     }

    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.tag == "FoodCube")
         {
            other.transform.position = new Vector3(Random.Range(0f, 28.5f), 0.25f, Random.Range(0f, 28.5f));
            counter++;
         }
    }

    private void OnGUI()
    {

        GUIStyle style = new GUIStyle();
        style.normal.textColor = Color.black;
        GUI.Label(new Rect(50, 10, 40, 40), counter.ToString(), style);

    }

}
```

Этот скрипт я привязал к своему главному кубику.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`OnTriggerEnter` работает исключительно с физикой, добавьте на оба объекты `RigidBody`, если физика не нужна, то просто заморозьте её по всем осям

Comment: Но в документации юнити написано, что работает и с Collider. Но раз так, то как заморозить по всем осям и что вы под этим имели ввиду?

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/2019.4/Manual/class-Rigidbody.html будет картинка, и если вы хотите, что бы на ваш объект не действовала физика, то включите все галки, которые видны на картинке

Comment: Ссылка битая, перенаправляет на пустую страницу Unity

Comment: Попробуйте ещё раз кликнуть

Comment: Также забыл уточнить, на isKinematic галка не нужна

Comment: Если моё решение вам помогло, то отметьте его как решение вопроса:)

Comment: Отметил, помогло, спасибо

Answer (score 4):

1. Один из объектов должен быть динамическим. То есть иметь компонент `RigidBody`. Два статических объекта не могут столкнуться, потому что не двигаются.
2. Динамический объект должен двигаться физически. То есть не изменением `transform`, а через тело `RigidBody.velocity`, `RigidBody.AddForce()` или самостоятельно двигаться скатываясь по поверхности и падая под действием гравитации.

`OnTrigger` функция для статических зон, что бы определять попадание чего либо, куда либо.